Proof of Cartan's Lemma in Lee's Smooth Manifolds
I am trying to prove problem 14-4 from Lee's Smooth manifolds.

CARTAN'S LEMMA: Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with or without
boundary, and let $\left(\omega^1, \ldots, \omega^k\right)$ be an
ordered $k$-tuple of smooth 1 -forms on an open subset $U \subseteq M$
such that $\left(\left.\omega^1\right|_p,
> \ldots,\left.\omega^k\right|_p\right)$ is linearly independent for
each $p \in U$. Given smooth 1 -forms $\alpha^1, \ldots, \alpha^k$ on
$U$ such that $$ \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^i \wedge \omega^i=0 $$ show that
each $\alpha^i$ can be written as a linear combination of $\omega^1,
> \ldots, \omega^k$ with smooth coefficients.

I use the following theorem

Proposition 10.15 (Completion of Local Frames for Vector Bundles). Suppose
$\pi: E \rightarrow M$ is a smooth vector bundle of rank $k$.
(a) If $\left(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_m\right)$ is a linearly
independent m-tuple of smooth local sections of $E$ over an open
subset $U \subseteq M$, with $1 \leq m<k$, then for each $p \in U$
there exist smooth sections $\sigma_{m+1}, \ldots, \sigma_k$ defined
on some neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $\left(\sigma_1, \ldots,
> \sigma_k\right)$ is a smooth local frame for $E$ over $U \cap V$.


Here is my proof:
Fix $p\in M$. By Proposition 10.15 (Completion of Local Frames for Vector Bundles),
there exists $V\subset U$ on which we can extend $\omega^1,\dots, \omega^k$ to a frame of the co-tangent bundle $\omega^1,\dots, \omega^k, v_{k+1},\dots, v_{n}$ over $V\cap U$. Now by the property from the question,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^i \land \omega^i=0,$$
we have that
\begin{align*}
\alpha^i\land \omega^i\\
= -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n\alpha^j \land\omega^j\\
 = -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (c_1^j\omega^1 + \dots+ c_k^j\omega^k + c_{k+1}^j v^{k+1}+\dots+ c_n^jv^n ) \land\omega^j\\
 = -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n c_1^j\omega^1\land\omega^j + \dots+ c_k^j\omega^k\land\omega^j + c_{k+1}^j v^{k+1}\land\omega^j+\dots+ c_n^jv^n\land\omega^j 
\end{align*}
And since
$$\alpha^i\land \omega^i = c_1^i\omega^1\land\omega^i + \dots+ c_k^i\omega^k\land\omega^i + c_{k+1}^i v^{k+1}\land\omega^i+\dots+ c_n^iv^n\land\omega^i,$$
equating
\begin{align*}
c_1^i\omega^1\land\omega^i + \dots+ c_k^i\omega^k\land\omega^i + c_{k+1}^i v^{k+1}\land\omega^i+\dots+ c_n^iv^n\land\omega^i\\
= -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n c_1^j\omega^1\land\omega^j + \dots+ c_k^j\omega^k\land\omega^j + c_{k+1}^j v^{k+1}\land\omega^j+\dots+ c_n^jv^n\land\omega^j 
\end{align*}
we see that it must be that $c^i_{k+1}=\dots= c^i_n = 0 $  proving that
$$\alpha_i = c_1^i\omega^i + \dots + c_k^i \omega^k.$$
on $V\cap U$. But how can I do this for all of U?
EDIT:
Consider the cover of $U$ $\mathcal{O}=\{V_p: p \in U\}$. Then take a partition of unity subordinate to this cover $\varphi_p$. Then
\begin{align*}
\alpha_i \\= \sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}}\varphi_V \alpha_i\\
=\sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}} \varphi_{V} (c_{1,V}\omega^1 + \dots + c_{k,V}^i \omega^k)\\= \left(\sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}} \varphi_V c_{1,V}^i\right)\omega^1 + \dots + \left(\sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}} \varphi_{V} c_{k,V}^i\right) \omega^k
\end{align*}
which is a smooth linear combination of $\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k$ on $U$.

My questions is this:
I can prove the theorem for a chart surrounding every point in $U$. But how can I then apply this reasoning to all of $U$? I wish that I could extend to a frame on the entirety of $U$ not just for a chart around every point.

Cover $U$ by such open sets $V$?

@TedShifrin Is there anything else to check? Or if I simply do it for every point in U, then I have the result? As I claimed in my edit

Well, no, as you want a global smooth linear combination. What’s the usual technique for gluing local things smoothly?

@TedShifrin Partition of unity!

@TedShifrin Do you agree with the edit I just made?

Your coefficient functions need to be indexed by $V$. You can certainly take a countable collection of $V$s rather than one for each point. But that’s not a huge issue. At any rate, at the end make sure you justify smoothness.

@TedShifrin Wouldn't we need compactness to take a finite sub-cover--how can I get countability? I think they are smooth because the partition of unity makes them smooth.

Yes, the point is that $\varphi_V f_V$ is a global smooth function when $f_V$ is a smooth function defined on the (open) set $V$. This is elementary, but the level at which you are writing suggests that it's worth getting this all correct. I never said a finite number of $V$; a countable collection follows from the fact that manifolds are second-countable (perhaps this doesn't follow from Lee's definition; I don't know).

One final comment: I presume Lee eventually gets to this (perhaps in a later part of the exercise), but one of the crucial consequences of the Cartan lemma is the stronger result that $\alpha^i = \sum f^i_j\omega^j$ with $f^i_j = f^j_i$. This symmetry condition is used powerfully in differential geometry, for example.

@TedShifrin Thank you for this comment! Lee does not seem to mention this. Is the sum indexed as $
\alpha^i=\sum_{i,j}^n f_j^i \omega^j
$ over all pairs $(i,j)$?

No, $1\le i,j\le k$ just as you've proved. So look carefully at your proof and you should see that you can immediately deduce $c^j_i = c^i_j$.

Oh wow I see that now! Thank you for pointing this out.

Why don't you write up a complete answer to your question for purposes of other people thinking about this matter?

@TedShifrin Great idea. I posted as an answer. Thank you!

CARTAN'S LEMMA: Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with or without
boundary, and let $\left(\omega^1, \ldots, \omega^k\right)$ be an
ordered $k$-tuple of smooth 1 -forms on an open subset $U \subseteq M$
such that $\left(\left.\omega^1\right|_p,
 \ldots,\left.\omega^k\right|_p\right)$ is linearly independent for
each $p \in U$. Given smooth 1 -forms $\alpha^1, \ldots, \alpha^k$ on
$U$ such that $$ \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^i \wedge \omega^i=0 $$ show that
each $\alpha^i$ can be written as a linear combination of $\omega^1,
 \ldots, \omega^k$ with smooth coefficients.

proof. Fix $p\in M$. By Proposition 10.15 (Completion of Local Frames for Vector Bundles),
there exists $V\subset U$ on which we can extend $\omega^1,\dots, \omega^k$ to a frame of the co-tangent bundle $\omega^1,\dots, \omega^k, v_{k+1},\dots, v_{n}$ over $V\cap U$. Now by the property from the question,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^i \land \omega^i=0,$$
we have that
\begin{align*}
\alpha^i\land \omega^i\\
= -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n\alpha^j \land\omega^j\\
 = -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (c_1^j\omega^1 + \dots+ c_k^j\omega^k + c_{k+1}^j v^{k+1}+\dots+ c_n^jv^n ) \land\omega^j\\
 = -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n c_1^j\omega^1\land\omega^j + \dots+ c_k^j\omega^k\land\omega^j + c_{k+1}^j v^{k+1}\land\omega^j+\dots+ c_n^jv^n\land\omega^j 
\end{align*}
And since
$$\alpha^i\land \omega^i = c_1^i\omega^1\land\omega^i + \dots+ c_k^i\omega^k\land\omega^i + c_{k+1}^i v^{k+1}\land\omega^i+\dots+ c_n^iv^n\land\omega^i,$$
equating
\begin{align*}
c_1^i\omega^1\land\omega^i + \dots+ c_k^i\omega^k\land\omega^i + c_{k+1}^i v^{k+1}\land\omega^i+\dots+ c_n^iv^n\land\omega^i\\
= -\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n c_1^j\omega^1\land\omega^j + \dots+ c_k^j\omega^k\land\omega^j + c_{k+1}^j v^{k+1}\land\omega^j+\dots+ c_n^jv^n\land\omega^j 
\end{align*}
we see that it must be that $c^i_{k+1}=\dots= c^i_n = 0 $  proving that
$$\alpha_i = c_1^i\omega^i + \dots + c_k^i \omega^k.$$
on $V\cap U$.
Consider the cover of $U$ where each of the $V_p$ are chosen as in the previous step. $\mathcal{O}=\{V_p: p \in U\}$, then choose a countable sub-cover. Then take a partition of unity subordinate to this cover $\{\varphi_V\}_{V\in \mathcal{O} }$. Then
\begin{align*}
\alpha_i \\= \sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}}\varphi_V \alpha_i\\
=\sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}} \varphi_{V} (c_{1,V}\omega^1 + \dots + c_{k,V}^i \omega^k)\\= \left(\sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}} \varphi_V c_{1,V}^i\right)\omega^1 + \dots + \left(\sum_{V\in \mathcal{O}} \varphi_{V} c_{k,V}^i\right) \omega^k
\end{align*}
which is a smooth linear combination of $\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k$ on $U$.

I should have commented earlier, but it's a bit cleaner just to keep the equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \alpha^i\wedge\omega^i = 0$, write $\alpha^i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n c^i_j\omega^j$, and then use linear independence of $\omega^j\wedge\omega^\ell$ for $1\le j<\ell\le n$ (rather than introducing different letters $v^\mu$).
